# Calculating the integrating factor that depends on $x$ and $y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can we know that the integrating factor of this ODE 
$$\left[ x+y\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \right]dx+\left[y+x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right]dy=0$$
to be exact is $$\mu(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
Is there any way to compute the integrating factor depending on x,y  if it is not given ?

Comment: I don't think for this **simple** equation you can find **hard way** to this  integrating factor. What's the benefits of this work?

Answer (score 1):

In the majority of the textbook cases, the integrating factor is simple, so that one can guess it by inspection and by trial and error. With a bit of intuition, this is the fastest method. But I suppose that is not the expected answer to your question.

A more systematic method can be used in some cases (but not all cases) : See Eqs.11, 12, 13 in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html

If all this fails, an even more systematic method consist in solving a PDE for $\mu(x,y)$ from :
$$\mu(x,y)\left[ x+y\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \right]dx+\mu(x,y)\left[y+x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right]dy=dF(x,y)=0$$
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\mu(x,y)\left[ x+y\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \right] \\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=\mu(x,y)\left[y+x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right]
\end{cases}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x\partial y}=\left[ x+y\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \right]\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y}+\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right)\mu$$
$$=\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y\partial x}=\left[ y+x\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \right]\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x}+\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right)\mu$$
The PDE to be solved for $\mu$ is :
$$\left[ y+x\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \right]\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x} - \left[ x+y\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \right]\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y}=\left(\frac{y^2-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right)\mu \tag 1$$
Again, an important simplification occurs if we guess that $\mu$ is on the form $\mu=f(X)$ with $X=x^2+y^2$. Putting it into $(1)$ and after simplification, leads to :
$$2X\frac{df}{dX}=-f(X) \quad\to\quad f(X)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{X}} \quad\to\quad \mu=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $$

If we don't guess the form $\mu=f(x^2+y^2)$ we have to solve the PDE $(1)$, with the method of characteristics for example. Note that we don't look for all solutions : only one (any one) is sufficient, which simplifies the task. Of course, this is an hard way. That is why this ultimate method is not recommended for textbook exercices, which are elementary so that the students are able to find the simpler alternatives.